# How can I filter a column for a list of data in excel without using VBA?

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with 14000 rows and 9 columns, first column is Name, second one is phone number etc... and I have a list of 100 phone numbers that I want to filter out, but so far I can only filter a single value in that list and get a single row as a result. but I would like to get all the rows with phone numbers that are in my list. How can I filter for more than one value?

Comment: What version of Excel are you working on?

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA:

First put your delete-list in **Z2** through **Z101**.  Then in column **10** cell **J2** enter:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B2,Z:Z,0)),"","KILL")
```

and copy downwards.  Filter on the newly added column and delete all `KILL` rows.

[image]

*(If you need to preserve the kill-list, place it on a separate sheet)*

Answer (score 0):

This formula looks for ***Name*** that ***match*** Phone
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do with Excels Advanced-Filter an without any helper column:

1) Goto Data
2) Choose Advanced Filter
3) Follow the Dialog

You can choose if you want to filter your Data on same place (overwrite the old one) or copy the filtered data on a new place. Also you can remove duplicates if necessary.

[image: Advanced-Filter]